# MySQL "UPDATE" syntax is entering 0 in column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update, ckeditor

I am trying to enter into a table in with PDO if using an if condition.  My code for the function is below:

```
function add_user_info($conn, $user, $info, $fName, $sName, $past, $pos){
    // Prepare and execute statements
    $info1 = addslashes($info);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `User_Info` WHERE `User` = '$user'");
    $sql->execute();
    if ($sql->fetch()){
        // Update current entry
        $sql1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `User_Info` SET `Info` = '$info1' AND `Past` = '$past' AND `Position` = '$pos' WHERE `User` = '$user'");
    } else {
        // Create new entry
        $sql1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `User_Info` (`User`, `Info`, `FName`, `SName`, `Past`, `Position`) VALUES ('$user', '$info1', '$fName', '$sName', '$past', '$pos')");
    }
    $sql1->execute();
}
```

The ONLY (I repeat, ONLY) part that is not working for me is on line 9 with the update query.  I have narrowed the problem down to it being related with the update of the `Info` column, and not only that but it is a problem with the string so the variable $info1.

I am trying to pass in a string of text from [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).  It is a rich text string and so has HTML tags, quotations, etc in it when passed to the SQL.

The initial creation of the row in the table (line 12 of the function) works PERFECTLY so it is only on the update that the string is seen as funny.  When I update with a word in place of $info1 it still does not work.

As shown in phpmyadmin, my table schema is as follows:

[image: User_Info table schema]

Comment: if any of the answers have helped you, kindly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update command multiple set is separated by `,` not `and`

```
UPDATE `User_Info` 
SET 
`Info` = '$info1' ,
`Past` = '$past' ,
`Position` = '$pos' 
WHERE `User` = '$user'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `AND` to `,`

```
$sql1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `User_Info` SET `Info`='$info1', `Past`='$past', `Position`='$pos' WHERE `User`='$user'");
```